Why is Neovim still setting text width based on my .editorconfig after disabling it?
I have a project with an .editorconfig file which sets max_line_length = 100. I can't stand this setting, and would rather not have Nvim changing settings on its own, so I went to disable editorconfig support by adding this line to my init.lua file:
vim.g.editorconfig = false

However, after doing so, I still notice the setting changing when I open a file in this project (files outside the project are unaffected). Deleting the .editorconfig file fixes the issue, so it's clearly getting this from the .editorconfig file. But why??

Ok, so...turns out this was a plugin called vim-sleuth, which also checks for an .editorconfig file.
The very helpful trick for figuring this out is to use:
:verbose set textwidth?

Which will tell you where the setting was last set.

You usually want to use option?; with a boolean option, :verbose set opt turns it on while :verbose set opt? reports the value and where it was last set.

Yes you're right, I forgot the ?
